# Random Image Generator not finding image in directory

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'm working on a very simple webpage that contains just a button that generates a random image above it.

I've searched online but none of the answers seem to solve my problem.

I have a js code that seems to be working: it generates a random number but when I try to link the number to '.jpg' (That's how all my images are named, ex: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc) it says

```
 " Failed to load resource:  [x].jpg:1 
    net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND "
```

it basically means that the function I have isn't adding the random number in the variable to the file name src.

I am sure that the name of the images are [number].jpg and that the directory is correct.

HTML:

```
     <body>
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <section class="row">
                  <div class="col-12" id="divImage"> </div>
              </section>
              <section class="row">
                  <button onclick="generator()"> Go </button>
              </section>
            </div>
          <script src="teste.js"></script>
      </body>
```

JS:

```
function generator() {
    var x= Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
    console.log(x);
    document.getElementById('divImage').innerHTML='<img src="img/[x].jpg">';
}
```

Comment: `.innerHTML='<img src="img/'+x+'.jpg">';`, your welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to interpolate a variable on a string use one of these:

```
'<img src="img/' + x +'.jpg">'
```

or with ES6

```
`<img src="img/${x}.jpg">`
```